# "Bundle "App" does not exist or it is not enabled

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, fosrestbundle

I'm getting this error when GETing`{{url}}/api/user/me`:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Bundle >"App" does not exist or it is not enabled. Maybe you forgot to add it in the >registerBundles() method of your App\Kernel.php file? in @App/Controller/UserController (which is being imported from "....\config/routes.yaml"). Make >sure the "App/Controller/UserController" bundle is correctly registered and >loaded in the application kernel class. If the bundle is registered, make >sure the bundle path "@App/Controller/UserController" is not empty.").

I'm using FOSRestBundle and FOSOauthBundle.

routes.yml

```
app_api:
  resource: "@App/Controller/UserController"
  type:     annotation
```

bundles.php

```
<?php

return [
    Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\FrameworkBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\SensioFrameworkExtraBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineCacheBundle\DoctrineCacheBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\DoctrineBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\MigrationsBundle\DoctrineMigrationsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\SecurityBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\SwiftmailerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\TwigBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MonologBundle\MonologBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\MakerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Symfony\Bundle\WebServerBundle\WebServerBundle::class => ['dev' => true],
    Nelmio\CorsBundle\NelmioCorsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle::class => ['dev' => true, 'test' => true],
    Stof\DoctrineExtensionsBundle\StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\OAuthServerBundle\FOSOAuthServerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\RestBundle\FOSRestBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    Nelmio\ApiDocBundle\NelmioApiDocBundle::class => ['all' => true],
    FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle::class => ['all' => true]
];
```

UserController

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Entity\User;
use App\Service\UserService;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\AbstractFOSRestController;
use FOS\RestBundle\Routing\ClassResourceInterface;
use FOS\RestBundle\View\View;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AccessDeniedException;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations\RouteResource;
use FOS\RestBundle\Controller\Annotations as Rest;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;

/**
 * @RouteResource("User")
 */
class UserController extends AbstractFOSRestController implements ClassResourceInterface
{
    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * @param TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage
     */
    public function __construct(TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }

    /**=
     * @Route("/api/user/me")
     * @Method("GET")
     *
     * @return User|string
     */
    public function getMeAction()
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY');

        $loggedInUser = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();

        return new Response($loggedInUser);
    }
```

composer.json

```
...
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
...
```

[Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWG4Y.png)

Comment: You would never actually have a bundle named App.  Hence the error.  Having an AppBundle used to be standard but not any more.  Just comment out the resource and type in routes.yml.  Unless you messed around with other config files, the user controller and annotations should still get picked up.

Comment: Hello, did you ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

The `@App/...` notation with the "at" symbol is used purely to resolve the location of a bundle.

You are trying to resolve the location of your project source files which do not live in a bundle.

In `routes.yml` try this instead:

```
app_api:
  resource: "../src/Controller/*"
  type:     annotation
```

Comment: but there are namespaces for that?